# Why deos Regex fail when case sensitive is used?

Tags: angularjs, regex, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

My regex is failing when case sensitivity is used.

This works fine: `var re = new RegExp(types);` against `"*pq*"`

This gives a console error: `var re = new RegExp(types, 'i');` against `"*pq*"`

Secondly when I match against "\" by typing in the input field it gives error why ?

Here is my code: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/e5zpSGWPZKPkSrpfSakr?p=preview

```
var re = new RegExp(types, 'i');
        angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
            if (item.name.match(re)) {
                console.log(item.name.match(types))
                filtered.push(item);
            }
        });
```

any update of this Question  ?

Comment: Try reading the error. It might contain clues about the problem.

Comment: yes pattern is incorrect...

Comment: please share plunker

Comment: what does `against "*pq*"` mean? Show us a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For filtering you should not use - `new RegExp()`. Because it won't escape special character which has special meanings in RegEx.

`\` has a special meaning in regex and there are other characters that needs to escape.

Like - `\/` can be used to escape `/`. Similarly `{`, `[` etc can be escaped as `\{` and `\[`.

**the best option could be:**

```
angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
    if(item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(types.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
        console.log("matched")
        filtered.push(item);
    }
});
```

**Edit**:
OP's custom requirement - [Updated Code Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/E3XoQ0n6AZM41vg89uhL?p=preview)

Comment: please share plunker ?

Comment: @user5711656, I have made changes, try this plunker....http://plnkr.co/edit/E3XoQ0n6AZM41vg89uhL?p=preview. You don't need "*" to match anythinng from starting or other etc...If this help then let me know else explain your requirement why you need to "*pq" etc and all other diff cases that you want to handle

Comment: I have four case ...if user type *pq ..it show all element which end with pq ..please check my plunker the output..secondly if user type `pq*` ..it show all item which start from pq..please check plunker

Comment: thirdly if user type  `pq*sv` ..it show all item which start from `pq` and  with `sv` ..which is working fine ..please check plunker

Comment: fourth if user type `*abc*` it show all items which have abc item in middle ..In my plunker all works fine.but have 2 issue case sensivtive and  "\" issue

Comment: @user5711656 Adding  other cases..wait

Comment: issue on "\" and case sensitive issue ..please check my plunker all case is working ..but "\" and case insenstive not

Comment: @user5711656 right your other cases working, exept `*something*`

Comment: @user5711656. please check this latest and let me know if your all cases working fine and after that I will update my answer. http://plnkr.co/edit/E3XoQ0n6AZM41vg89uhL?p=preview